# How to retain midi quirks in final recording with Logic Pro

Tags: recording, midi, logic-pro

I've got a song that I'm working on which has an Alchemy (Descending Below) synth track. At the end of the song, I do a progressive tempo slowdown, ending at about 5bpm. When the synth track ends, there's this cute little deflating noise as the output dies off--sort of like a baritone sad whistle.

I'd share a sample here, but that's the problem. I can't.

When I actually bounce the song, or save it to the media browser as an AIF, that sound gets cut off. Logic is helpfully removing all the artefacts. But I want this artefact, and don't know how to keep it.

The only solution I can think of is to capture the computer's output using a separate recorder, then topping and tailing the resulting file.

But that seems like overkill. Is there some easier way to record my song with all the artefacts intact?

Comment: Did you try to prolongue the song for a few bars?

Answer (score 1):

If @ToddWilcox's method doesn't work, try this out.

Bounce the `Alchemy (Descending Below) synth` track to a separate audio track by either right clicking on the synth track and selecting the

> **Bounce and Join > Bounce in Place**

or use the shortcut key

> **^B**

[image]

a dialogue box like this will appear
[image]

Check the following options

> Include Audio Tail in File
>
> > Include Audio Tail in Region

this will convert everything, that routes from the `Alchemy (Descending Below) synth` track to the main-out including the effects tail, into a separate audio track.

Mute the `Alchemy (Descending Below) synth` (MIDI) track and then bounce the whole song.

Answer (score 0):

When you bounce, part of the bounce dialog should be asking you the timeframe that you want to bounce. Make sure you specify the bounce start and end and when you do, make sure you add enough time at the end to capture all the tails of anything that shouldn't be cut off.

Logic will try to automatically set the start and end points, but it's not very intelligent about it, so it will usually get it wrong. Don't let it do it automatically, do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

A 'live' audio capture may be the right answer.   Does it have to be to a different device?  Does it even have to be to a different DAW program?